# Python Locust 'locust' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, command-prompt, locust

I am using locust package which uses python. I am following this tutorial:

https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#example-locustfile-py

But when i get to executing this code in command line;

```
locust locustfile.py
```

I get this error;

```
'locust' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have succesfully installed locust using pip

Any help apperciated! (sorry for bad English it is not my first language)

Comment: The response of @user10788336 should be helpful.
Also you should consider creating a python virtual environment to isolate your developement: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Answer (score 3):

This could be an issue with setting environment variable - Path for Python37/Scripts location

You may refer to this link with a similar issue:

[Not able to install locust on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687223/not-able-to-install-locust-on-windows/57977255?noredirect=1#comment102365135_57977255)

Answer (score 1):

After installing locust using pip3 I appended `C:/Python37/Scripts` to the `Path` environment variable in windows. Restarted the terminal afterwards and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you need to add `%APPDATA%\Python\Python311\Scripts` to the `PATH` environment variable