# Not able to install locust on windows

Tags: python, locust

I installed locust using the command on windows

```
py -m pip install locustio
```

This is the output I got

```
Collecting locustio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/12/60351b28a00c76d36022d79bead7dc217e9e49cddd7091cb164319196323/locustio-0.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting gevent>=1.2.2 (from locustio)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/dd/417aad4e69fa7f8882534b778c46cb28eb0421ffa1e924ec3b4efcfcc81f/gevent-1.4.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (3.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.0MB 356kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.9.1 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from locustio) (2.22.0)
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from locustio)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting msgpack>=0.4.2 (from locustio)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/67/476640810609471e0f3a32c9f4388bf1318b773d0a64b116305d3b604dca/msgpack-0.6.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (68kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 354kB/s
Collecting flask>=0.10.1 (from locustio)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/93/628509b8d5dc749656a9641f4caf13540e2cdec85276964ff8f43bbb1d3b/Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyzmq>=16.0.2 (from locustio)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/15/27d1655af3f96c59073073b03022c6a0c1cbfa583c036b46ae8c33d51ee6/pyzmq-18.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.1MB 314kB/s
Collecting cffi>=1.11.5; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython" (from gevent>=1.2.2->locustio)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/ad/9722b7752fdd88c858be57b47f41d1049b5fb0ab79caf0ab11407945c1a7/cffi-1.12.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (171kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 174kB 108kB/s
Collecting greenlet>=0.4.14; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" (from gevent>=1.2.2->locustio)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/a3/da8593df08ee2efeb86ccf3201508a1fd2a3749e2735b7cadb7dd00416c6/greenlet-0.4.15-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio) (1.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio) (2.8)
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24 (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ae/44b03b253d6fade317f32c24d100b3b35c2239807046a4c953c7b89fa49e/itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Jinja2>=2.10.1 (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/e7/fd8b501e7a6dfe492a433deb7b9d833d39ca74916fa8bc63dd1a4947a671/Jinja2-2.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.15 (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/ab/d3bed6b92042622d24decc7aadc8877badf18aeca1571045840ad4956d3f/Werkzeug-0.15.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click>=5.1 (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/37/45185cb5abbc30d7257104c434fe0b07e5a195a6847506c074527aa599ec/Click-7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.11.5; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"->gevent>=1.2.2->locustio)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/9e/49196946aee219aead1290e00d1e7fdeab8567783e83e1b9ab5585e6206a/pycparser-2.19.tar.gz
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask>=0.10.1->locustio)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/c6/2399700d236d1dd681af8aebff1725558cddfd6e43d7a5184a675f4711f5/MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, greenlet, gevent, six, msgpack, itsdangerous, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, click, flask, pyzmq, locustio
  Running setup.py install for pycparser ... done
  The script flask.exe is installed in 'C:\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script locust.exe is installed in 'C:\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed Jinja2-2.10.1 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-0
```

Now when I run the command locust --help

I get this on the command line

```
'locust' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

What could be the issue?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The locus is downloaded in the Scripts folder. The Scripts folder must be added to environmental path to access `locus`, `python`, `pip` and other python commands

Comment: The script locust.exe is installed in 'C:\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have not added python 3.7 in the environment variable PATH. While this could have been achieved while installing python itself by checking the box to Add Python to the path. However, you can still add the location of Python37(where python37 is installed) by going to *This PC--Right-Click->Properties-->Advanced System Settings-->Environment Variables tab-->System Variables--Edit Path* & add value*.

I recently wrote steps for setting up locust on windows which might help -https://www.qamilestone.com/post/set-up-locust-on-windows
-Regards,
Anuradha

Comment: If I were you, I would say to add `C:/Python37/Scripts` after taking a look on output rather than telling to _add the location of Python37_

Comment: Accepted. That makes more sense:).Thanks